# Optional Text in Alert in ResetPassword - iOS Project using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alert

Here's my ResetPassword Button for my iOS application using xcode and swift:

```
//ResetPssword Button
@IBAction func ResetPassword(sender: AnyObject) {

    if validateEmail(EmailTextField.text!) ==  false {
        print("Enter a Valid Email Address")
        let VaildMessage = "Enter an Email Address"
        //Empty TextField Alert Message
        self.disaplayErrorMessage(VaildMessage)
   }

    //Reset
    else {

        ref.resetPasswordForUser(EmailTextField.text) { (ErrorType) -> Void in
            if ErrorType != nil {

                let error = ErrorType
                print("There was an error processing the request \(error.description)")
                let errorMessage:String = "The Email You Entered is not Exist"
                //Error Alert Message
                self.disaplayErrorMessage(errorMessage)

            } else {

                print("Password Reset Sent Successfully")
                let successMessage = "Email Message was Sent to You at \(self.EmailTextField.text)"

                //Success Alert Message
                self.disaplayErrorMessage(successMessage)
            }

    } //reset

    } //Big Else

 } //Button


//Display Alert Message With Confirmation
func disaplayErrorMessage(theMessage:String)
{
    //Display alert message with confirmation.
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: theMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
    }
    myAlert.addAction(OkAction);
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


   //Validate Email Function
func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluateWithObject(candidate)
}
```

If the password reset sent successfully, there will be an alert that prints out the email address. But it prints email with optional word!

[image]

How can I print it without the optional word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *unwrap* the Optional text field.

For example with `if let`:

```
if let text = self.EmailTextField.text {
    let successMessage = "Email Message was Sent to You at \(text)"
    //Success Alert Message
    self.disaplayErrorMessage(successMessage)
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that the textfield exist you can force the unwrap using `"Email Message was Sent to You at \(text!)"`

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to force unwrap the value using the `!` sign ?

Comment: No! How can I do that?

Comment: If you are sure that your textfield exists, you can do `Email Message was Sent to You at \(self.EmailTextField!.text)`