# displaying user email on viewcontroller gives optional"email adress"

Tags: swift, firebase

So I'm using firebase Authentication in my ios app, and I want to display the email address, and Username in UIlabels on a viewcontroller. But when i display the value of `Auth.auth().email` on a UIlabel, the Label would show `Optional"email adress"`.How do i get rid of the Optional and also how to allow the user to have a display name in firebase Authentication?

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var profiepic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var league: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Achievements: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resetpasswd: UIButton!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        UsernameLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        EmailLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        league.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        Achievements.layer.cornerRadius = 55/2
        resetpasswd.layer.cornerRadius = 55/2
        resetpasswd.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        displayinfo()
    }
    func displayinfo() {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if let user = user {
          // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
          // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
          // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
          let email = user.email
          let photoURL = user.photoURL
            EmailLabel.text = "Email: \(email)"
          // ...
        }
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: You can find the solution in this thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944483/optional-text-in-alert-in-resetpassword-ios-project-using-swift]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `if` or `guard` to display string info properly.

**Using `if`**:

```
func displayinfo() {
     let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
     if let user = user {
          if let email = user.email {
               EmailLabel.text = "Email: \(email)"
          }

          if let photoURL = user.photoURL {
             ...
          }
          // ...
    }
}
```

**Using `guard`**:

```
func displayinfo() {
     guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
         print("No user info found")
         return
     }

     if let email = user.email {
         EmailLabel.text = "Email: \(email)"
         //EmailLabel.text = "Email: " + email
     }

     if let photoURL = user.photoURL {
         ...
     }
     // ...
}
```

Let me know if you have any issue in these solutions.

Apart from this, I would rather write UIViewController in this manner which seems to be a more clearer approach.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var profiepic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblUsername: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            lblUsername.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var lblEmail: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            lblEmail.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var lblLeague: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            lblLeague.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var btnAchievements: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            btnAchievements.layer.cornerRadius = 55/2
            // For button height, instead of 55 here you can use, btnAchievements.bounds.height / 2 or use constrain also to change button height when bound changes
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var btnReset: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            btnReset.layer.cornerRadius = 55/2
            btnReset.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        }
    }

    private var currentUser: AuthUser? {// Type of Auth.auth().currentUser
        didSet {
            // Use above code for displayInfo or simply call displayInfo from here
        }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    }
    
    ...
}
```

I hope this would help you designing other `UIViewController`s as well.